# Look And Feel in Java Applet Doesn't Work

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel, japplet, nimbus

I use the following code to set the look and feel for my Java Applet. This completely works inside a Java Application.

### EDIT

```
@Override
public void init() {

    try {
        //This sets the look and feel to NIMBUS.
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    initComponents();
        //Calls the method showStartScreen()
        startGame();

}
```

This works at random times on my web page. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: When I run the applet, it shows the default look-and-feel. It doesn't show the Nimbus look-and-feel.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is being executed? Have you tried looking at it with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of BIG Nimbus fans

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class NimbusSizing implements Runnable, ItemListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JSpinner spinner;
    private JComboBox combo;
    private JRadioButton radio;
    private JCheckBox check;
    private JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new NimbusSizing());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + info);
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        combo = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"mini", "small", "regular", "large"});
        combo.setSelectedIndex(2);
        combo.addItemListener(this);
        spinner = new JSpinner();
        radio = new JRadioButton("Radio");
        check = new JCheckBox("Check");
        button = new JButton("Button");
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, true).
                addComponent(spinner).addComponent(radio).
                addComponent(check).addComponent(button).addComponent(combo));
        final int sz = GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE;
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addComponent(spinner, sz, sz, sz).
                addComponent(radio, sz, sz, sz).addComponent(check, sz, sz, sz).
                addComponent(button, sz, sz, sz).addComponent(combo, sz, sz, sz));
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            resize((String) combo.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }

    private void resize(String value) {
        System.out.println("resize(" + value + ")");
        System.out.println("\t" + spinner.isFontSet() + " " + System.identityHashCode(spinner.getFont()) + " " + spinner.getFont());
        spinner.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", value);
        combo.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", value);
        radio.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", value);
        check.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", value);
        button.putClientProperty("JComponent.sizeVariant", value);
        spinner.setFont(null);
        for (int i = spinner.getComponentCount(); --i >= 0;) {
            spinner.getComponent(i).setFont(null);
        }
        radio.setFont(null);
        check.setFont(null);
        button.setFont(null);
        combo.setFont(null);
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        System.out.println("\t" + spinner.isFontSet() + " " + System.identityHashCode(spinner.getFont()) + " " + spinner.getFont());
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is for a java application and not for applet. For applications the nimbus works like this, however for applet it doesn't work, even if you set it in the init method.

Answer (score 0):

What exception are you getting when calling the code?

If there is no exception, do you always call the look and feel change before ANYTHING is painted?

And last, could it be the user doesn't have that look and feel setup/installed?

Comment: There is no exception. It is located in the init() method, right after initComponents(). I didn't know I had to paint it... Anyways, it randomly decides to work on my browser. I was just trying to find out how to make it work full time.

Comment: I just edited the code shown above, showing my entire init() method.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the process in browser? If you can't, can you dump a ridiculous number of print statements to get information?

Comment: I guess I'll do some debugging.